# Get date value back in fullcalendar when right-clicking an open cell

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I created a jsfiddle to show my problem.  Basically I want to have fullcalender render a calendar in "agendaweek" view, and allow the user to right-click on an open cell and retrieve the date/time into a JS variable that I can use for further functionality.  Left-mouse-clicking works, but right-mouse-clicking does not in "agendaWeek" view.  What's most important to me is to be able to retrieve the clicked date/time of that open cell when right-clicked.  I've scoured the web and have seen lots of examples of popping up contextual menus, but nothing that actually works within fullcalendar to retrieve the *right-clicked* date/time into a JS variable.  If anyone can show me how that's done, I'd be very grateful.  Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/gouldtv/1j01ztdm/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
             var formattedDate = date.toString().replace(" GMT+0000",""); 
            alert("see, I can get " + formattedDate + " if I _left click_, but try doing this with a right click");
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    });

});
```

Comment: Would it help if I offered $50 Paypal transfer to the first person who can show me this working in JS-fiddle?  (Right click on a day-cell, and alert the date/time)

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is the proper answer what you are expecting but it might give you some idea on how to manipulate further. Just add below lines which gets the co-ordinates on right click of full calendar.

```
function CustomContext() {    
    var e = window.event;        
    var x=e.clientX;        
    var y=e.clientY;
    if (e.which === 3 || e.button === 2) {
         alert('Right Click happend at ' + x +' ' + y);
    }    
}

$("#calendar").mousedown(CustomContext);
```

Try manipulating the coordinates and I think you can either create your own context if you dig deep in the google or you can just get date and time based on the co-ordinates

Comment: I know what you are saying, but unfortunately I haven't found a way to get the date/time information out of fullcalendar based on the x,y coordinates of a mouse-click.  Looking in firebug at the DOM elements, I don't see a way to get that information via coordinates.  I suspect that fullcalendar is stashing the date/time data as jQuery ui.data but it is not clear how to get it out in this special case.

Comment: Yea. I agree. If they would have added an `event` parameter in `dayRender`, it would have been good. It is there in `eventRender`. Some jquery experts may try overriding that `dayRender` from plugin..

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty cheesy, but by modifying fullcalendar.js, you can insert the datetime into an attribute of the row element as it's being rendered.  Then you can hook the right-click and picks up the attribute from the element that was clicked.

In fullcalendar.js, modify slatRowHtml() to insert the datetime:

```
html += '<tr event-time="' + slotDate.format() + '" ' .....
```

Then bind to the mousedown event and filter for right-click (which == 3):

```
$"(#calendar").find(".fc-agendaDay-view .fc-time-grid tr").bind("mousedown", function (e) {

    if (e.which == 3) {
        alert($(this).attr("event-time"));
    }

});
```

Note: I've only implemented this for the agendaDay view, but I'm sure you can figure out how to do it for agendaWeek as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/hammerbeam/96hdqoa5/